# How to fetch one value from list in a column for grouped data in Pig Script

Tags: apache-pig

I have data getting fetched using Pig Script as -

GENERATE COUNT(C) as kount, group.methodName, group.pool, MIN(C.time), MAX(C.time), **C.FlowId**
};

Here FlowId(alphanumeric) is a list with multiple ids corresponding to different occurrences of method names but I need only one id which can be any from the list.
How can I achieve this using Pig Script?
So, Basically in the above query how do get a single flow Id instead of list of flow ids?

Any pointers would be appreciated..

I tried MAX for Flow ID but i would not work since Flow ID is alphanumeric.

Comment: Solved it using -
E = FOREACH D {
sorted = order C by time desc;
top    = limit sorted 1;
GENERATE COUNT(C) as kount,flatten(top), MIN(C.time);
};

The flatten top will have the latest Flow ID based on time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using -

E = FOREACH D { sorted = order C by time desc; top = limit sorted 1; GENERATE COUNT(C) as kount,flatten(top), MIN(C.time); };

The flatten top will have the latest Flow ID based on time